# Creating a check box with boolean value connected to API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean

I have a react application pulling data from an API that is an array of objects.
One of the values is a boolean value and I am creating a check box that when clicked it changes the boolean value from true to false.

Example of the API data:

```
[{created: "Nov 10"}, { created_by: "Tim"}, {is_active: true}]
[{created: "Nov 15"}, { created_by: "Bill"}, {is_active: false}]
```

I created a table to map through the data. Below is the example:

```
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([])
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

{data.map((group, i) => (
<tr key={i}>
 <td> {data.created}</td>
 <td> {data.created_by}</td>
<td> <checkbox value={data.is_active}
      checked={checkedItem}
      onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxChange(e.target.checked, i)}
/></td>
<tr>
)}
```

I set up my `handleCheckboxChange` and passed through `e`, `checked` and `i`, but not to sure about the logic to change the value of `is_active` from true / false when the checkbox is clicked.
This is what I was thinking to change the state but react is not recognizing the value of the boolean accessed from the API data. I don't think the logic is correct.

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (e, checked, i) => {
let newChecked = checkedItems.map((x) => x);
      newChecked ? setCheckedItems(false) : setCheckedItems(true);
      setCheckedItems(newChecked)
     }
```

How do I use react to set state of the boolean value pulled from an API?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected mapping function:

```
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([])
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

{data.map((item, i) => (
  <tr key={i}>
    <td>{item.created}</td>
    <td>{item.created_by}</td>
    <td>
      <checkbox
        value={item.is_active}
        checked={checkedItems[i] || false}
        onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxChange(e.target.checked, i)}
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Here is the logic to update the state based on the checkbox changes:

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (checked, i) => {
  setCheckedItems((prevCheckedItems) => {
    const newCheckedItems = [...prevCheckedItems];
    newCheckedItems[i] = checked;
    return newCheckedItems;
  });
};
```